# Microsoft Graph teams remove rejectedSender call returns error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use [this](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/group_delete_rejectedsenders) API to remove a user from the list of rejected senders. Based on the examples in this documentation, I am trying to call the API as `DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/GROUP_ID/rejectedSenders/$ref?$id="users/USER_ID"`, but this and all variants of it that I have tried return the following:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InternalServerError",
    "message": "This operation is not supported for a relative URI.",
    "innerError": {
    "request-id": "e90009a6-b6d0-405c-abe2-aef396ca43de",
    "date": "2017-06-05T19:14:16"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a fully qualified path without the double quotes. For example:

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/GROUP_ID/rejectedSenders/$ref?$id=https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/USER_ID
```